# Solspace SuperSearch giving 'You are not allowed to search' on live site

Tags: solspace, supersearch

Using Solspace SuperSearch in ExpressionEngine site works OK on test site.

When running behind the network firewalls and load-balancing systems produces
"You are not allowed to search."

The form POSTS, but then does not redirect onto the results page.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Super Search are you using? What version of EE are you using? Have you checked your .htaccess file? Something is likely different on your live server if the form worked on your test server.

Comment: This is a site I have inherited. 
ExpressionEngine 2.5.5  SuperSearch 2.0.6  
Running on Windows server 2k8 behind firewalls / loadbalancers.

Using the direct URL works fine.

Comment: First try to update to the latest version (2.1.3 as of this writing). Then, make sure your domain in the browser and the domain set in EE are **exactly** the same (by the way, www and non-www are different). Finally, check your redirection setting in EE, and try the other option if one doesn't work.

Comment: Eureka !
The error is caused by Expression Engine and not SuperSearch.  If you have this error - PLEASE check your **blacklist**.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments above by new2EE, this was caused by a blacklist setting in EE.